# What is the best extraction program to use in Windows 7?

Tags: zip, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best compression applications for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37815/best-compression-applications-for-windows)

What is the best extraction program to use in Windows 7?

Do people still prefer winrar or 7zip? 
Which or another is best for all round format support and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7zip for my Open Source loving soul
WinRar when I need to get working

Answer (score 3):

7zip still rox.